# Change height of JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Is it possible to increase the height of a `JComboBox`?(not refering to the popup menu)

Have tried:

```
comboBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
```

and

```
Component[] comp = comboBox.getComponents();
for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
    if (comp[i] instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) comp[i];
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

    }
}
```

But no luck. 
Then I tried to fix the problem with layout managers:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weighty = 1;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
panel.add(cbox, c);
```

But this dose not seems to change the size of the `JComboBox` button.

```
public class ComboBoxFontChange extends JFrame {

    public ComboBoxFontChange() {

        // CREATE BOX
        JComboBox<String> cbox = new JComboBox<String>();
        cbox.setFont(cbox.getFont().deriveFont(30.0f));

        // TRY CHANGE SIZE: DOSE NOT WORK..
        cbox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        cbox.setSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        cbox.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));

        // TRY CHANGE SIZE ON BUTTON INSTEAD: DOSE NOT WORK..
        Component[] comp = cbox.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < comp.length; i++) {
            if (comp[i] instanceof JButton) {
                JButton btn = (JButton) comp[i];
                btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
                btn.setSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
                btn.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
            }
        }
        cbox.addItem("Quarter");
        cbox.addItem("Nickel");
        cbox.addItem("Penny");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(cbox);

        getContentPane().add(panel);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComboBoxFontChange frame = new ComboBoxFontChange();
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to manage size with help of `LayoutManager`. What really you want to do with height?

Comment: Take a look at [JComboBox tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer). You may want a custom `ListCellRenderer`

Comment: Try `setMaximumRowCount()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8275711/230513).

Comment: @alex2410 Added a layout manager try but with no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: @peeskillet I believe the ListCellRenderer only concerns the popup menu?

Comment: @Grains take a look at my answer with the image of the result

Comment: @trashgod setMaximumRowCount() only concerns the popup menu?

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(cbox);
```

By default [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) has a [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) as layout manager and this one doesn't honor the components preferred size. It just fits the components using their minimum possible size. As @alex2410 says in his comment you need to manage components size and position by using a proper [Layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Also take a look to this topic: [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Added a layout manager try but with no luck. Any idea why?

Comment: @Grains I tried with `BorderLayout`, `BoxLayout` and `GridLayout` and all of them honor the combo box preferred size (all tried on Windows 8 but this must be platform independent). About the buttons size it has something to do with the layout manager that `JComboBox` uses to lay out its internal components (I suspect it uses `FlowLayout` as well) and that's why setting the buttons preferred size doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this code. Using custom [`ListCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) I set the preferred size the of the visible cell.

You can use the following code class `CustomComboBox` and just change the dimension of the `getPreferredSize` of the `JLabel`.

And then for your `comboBox` just set the renderer `comboBox.setRenderer(newCustomComboBox());`

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ComboBoxDemo extends JFrame {

    JComboBox cbo = new JComboBox(new String[] {"Hello, StackOverflow"});

    public ComboBoxDemo(){
        cbo.setRenderer(new CustomComboBox());
        add(cbo, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JLabel("Hello"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new ComboBoxDemo();
            }
        });
    }

    static class CustomComboBox extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                JList list, 
                Object value, 
                int index, 
                boolean isSelected, 
                boolean cellHasFocus) {

            JLabel label = new JLabel(){
                public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                    return new Dimension(200, 100);
                }
            };
            label.setText(String.valueOf(value));

            return label;
        }
    }        
}
```

[image]

[image]

[ListCellRenderer javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) | [JComboBox/ListCellRenderer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)

Comment: This is how it looks at startup on my Mac: http://i.imgur.com/ezgWR1e.png. No difference in height :(

Comment: Sorry this didn't help. I Tried. I have no experience with Mac :(